# How to send decimal as a argument in the c# method

Tags: c#, arguments

I have a simple class which has a constructor in this manner:

```
public Components(int sNo, string componentName, string fileType, **decimal size**, int totalDownloads, string filePath, **decimal price**, string description)
```

i'm trying to send the arguments by calling this statement:

```
new DatabaseObjects.Components(1, "CC Cleaner", "exe", **2,84**, 0, @"C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Software_Components\CCCleaner.exe", **5,00**, "To clean up junk files and invalid Registry entries")
```

But as you can see when i try to send the arguments in this way it is not taking 2,84 as one value it is taking 2 as one argument and 84 as one argument.

and when i try to replace ,with . *i mean 2,84 as 2.84*

it is saying cannot convert double to decimal.

How can i solve this problem ?

Please help me

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the [decimal literal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx) `2.84m`.

Plain `2.84` is parsed as a [double](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/678hzkk9.aspx), which cannot be implicitly converted to a `decimal`.